# How to set voxel value based on absolute distances/coordinates from origin in simpleITK

Tags: python, 3d, itk, simpleitk, medical-imaging

I have a dicom 3D image and additional file describing binary mask. Binary mask is encoded with XYZ coordinates:

5.123422, 6.123123, 5.123123; 5.123422, 6.123123, 5.123123; 5.123422, 6.123123, 5.123123 ...

I want to transform those encoded points into dicom (or other 3d format I can convert). Since dicom structure has fixed dimensions between its voxels and this structure is known. I am guessing that I can just read coordinates from file and set values of the points based on proximity. Are there better solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a job for [TransformPhysicalPointToIndex](https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1ImageBase.html#ae46118e0a604c11e6f1170da7c478f81) in a for loop:

```
for (auto p in points)
{
  auto index = maskImage->TransformPhysicalPointToIndex(p);
  maskImage->SetPixel(index, 255); // desired label
}
```

I don't think there are better solutions (based on my understanding of your problem).